# Could someone help me with my code (Python functions)

Tags: python

```
import random
import time

global score
global cpuscore

score = 1
cpuscore = 1    


print("Current score CPU:Player = 1 , 1 ")

def plus():

    rand1 = random.randint(2,99)

    rand2 = random.randint(2,99)

    ans = (rand1 + rand2)

    print("What's", rand1, "+" ,rand2,)

    quest = int(input())                      

    if quest == ans:

        print("Correct")

        score + 1

    else:

        print("Incorrect")

        cpuscore + 1

def multiply():

    rand1 = random.randint(2,99)

    rand2 = random.randint(2,99)

    ans = (rand1 + rand2)

    print("What's", rand1, "+" ,rand2,)

    quest = int(input())                      

    if quest == ans:

        print("Correct")

        score + 1

    else:

        print("Incorrect")

        cpuscore + 1


def subtract():

    rand1 = random.randint(2,99)

    rand2 = random.randint(2,99)

    ans = (rand1 + rand2)

    print("What's", rand1, "+" ,rand2,)

    quest = int(input())                      

    if quest == ans:

        print("Correct")

        score + 1

    else:

        print("Incorrect")

        cpuscore + 1


print("Welcome to eleven elves")

print("Please name your elves")


elf1 = input("Elf 1: ")
elf2 = input("Elf 2: ")
elf3= input("Elf 3: ")
elf4 = input("Elf 4: ")
elf5 = input("Elf 5: ")
elf6 = input("Elf 6: ")
elf7 = input("Elf 7: ")
elf8 = input("Elf 8: ")
elf9 = input("Elf 9: ")
elf10 = input("Elf 10: ")
elf11 = input("Elf 11: ")



print("So let me just clarrify, the name of your eleven elves throughout this quest will be")




clar = str.lower(input("Is this correct? (Yes or No) "))

if clar == ("yes"):
    print("Ok, let's continue on")
else:
    print("Would you to change the name of your elves?")
    clar2 = str.lower(input("Yes or No "))
    if clar2 == ("yes"):
        elf1 = input("Elf 1: ")
        elf2 = input("Elf 2: ")
        elf3= input("Elf 3: ")
        elf4 = input("Elf 4: ")
        elf5 = input("Elf 5: ")
        elf6 = input("Elf 6: ")
        elf7 = input("Elf 7: ")
        elf8 = input("Elf 8: ")
        elf9 = input("Elf 9: ")
        elf10 = input("Elf 10: ")
        elf11 = input("Elf 11: ")
        print("Elf names changed.")
    else:
        print("Ok no problem, let's continue on")

print(elf1, "enters a cave... The cave is full of monsters and creepy crawlys, a monster pops out             of no where, the monster says.. Dear old dear old", elf1 ,"Why are you all by your self? You wanna get past, you gotta' get asked do you accept or run away?")
q1 = str.lower(input("Do you accept the challenge... ('you get the drift now yes or no....') "))

if q1 == ("yes"):

    plus()

    print("Current score CPU:Player", cpuscore, score)

else:

    print(elf1, "runs away")

    print(cpuscore)
```

I want my code to add 1 to "score" if the question is correct, the same way it should add 1 to "cpuscore" but when I run the code and get the question correct, it still prints the new score as 1, it's really confusing and I cannot figure out why. I am new to python so I really wouldn't mind some help.

The problem still persists

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Open Me x\Computing\Mrs Farakh\Programming\Python\Assessment.py", line 139, in <module>
plus()
  File "N:\Open Me x\Computing\Mrs Farakh\Programming\Python\Assessment.py", line 27, in plus
    score += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't match the traceback. Please edit your post to clarify your problem.

Comment: I think the statement "The problem still persists" and the traceback describe what happened when he tried to implement Bhat Irshad's answer.  That makes sense since the answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is this,

```
score + 1
```

It should be,

```
score = score + 1
```

You need to create a def function to assign global variables, otherwise the global function is completely useless.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Integers are `immutable` in python. There is no **in-place** modification to integers in **python** like in **C**. You need to reassign the value after every increment.

Replace:

```
score + 1
```

by

```
score += 1  # or score = score + 1
```

and

```
cpuscore + 1  # or cpuscore = cpuscore + 1
```

by

```
cpuscore += 1
```

Make your variables global in every function where you modify those variables as:

```
def plus():
    global score 
    global cpuscore 

def subtract():
    global score 
    global cpuscore
```

Comment: The `global` keyword is _totally useless_ outside a function's body.

Comment: If you put the global statements INSIDE the function body of plus(), instead of at the beginning of the script, your other suggested change will work.  The multiply() function has the same problem but it never gets called.